# Google Sheet Custom Function - how get cell locations from a range if cell is not blank

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Not sure if I can do this, but if I have 4 non-blank cells in a column (say A4, A29, A30, and A62), can I get an array of those via a function, i.e. [A4, A29, A30, A62].

Cheers,
Huck

---

---

Update - So I'm attempting to roll the solution into a custom formula

I've got:

```
function test(passedRange){
  // return firt entry
  // call wthi "==test(General!A4:A62)"
  var rangeToLoopThrough = [];
  rangeToLoopThrough =   {"A"&substitute(TEXTJOIN(",A",,ArrayFormula(row(passedRange)*(passedRange<>""))),",A0","")};
  return rangeToLoopThrough[0];
};
```

it complains about

> "Missing : after property ID" on row 5.

I think it is not liking the passedRange.  Shouldn't you be able to pass a range into a custom formula?

Cheers,
Huck

Comment: Something like =filter(A4:A62, len(A4:A62)) ?

Answer (score 1):

Pending a better solution/clearer Q, please try:

```
="A"&substitute(TEXTJOIN(",A",,ArrayFormula(row(A4:A62)*(A4:A62<>""))),",A0","")
```

Comment: Does ArrayFormula return an array?  I was hoping to incorporate into a custom function.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the curly brackets solution:

{A4, A29, A30, A62} will give you an array that's a row with four columns
{A4; A29; A30; A62} will give you an array that's a column with four rows

And you can take it from there.

More here under the Create arrays heading:  https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en

Comment: So I was attempting to convert this to custom function, but I think I'm failing to see how to implement the array. I'll add it into the upper question.

Comment: Now I see, the curly brackets only work in formulas within the sheet. Have a look at this then: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list.
You'll probably want to add your range into a variable (say myRange) and then use string replace() to do the substitution (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Custom function is not necessary. You can use FILTER:

```
=FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"")
```